# Ruby on Rails 2: Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Пытаюсь оживить <strike>динозавра</strike> один старый проект на Rails 2, но получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
[REQUEST FAILED] curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/prices/price/_search?size=20&pretty' -d '{"facets":{"groups":{"terms":{"field":"id_group","size":1000,"all_terms":false},"facet_filter":{"and":[{"term":{"id_group":"1"}}]}},"groups_subgroups":{"terms":{"field":"groups_subgroups","size":1000,"all_terms":false},"facet_filter":{"and":[{"term":{"id_group":"1"}}]}},"cat_filter":{"terms":{"field":"cat_filter","size":1000,"all_terms":false}},"id_firm":{"terms":{"field":"id_firm","size":10000,"all_terms":false},"facet_filter":{"and":[{"term":{"id_group":"1"}}]}},"tag":{"terms":{"field":"tag","size":1000,"all_terms":false},"facet_filter":{"and":[{"term":{"id_group":"1"}}]}},"subtag":{"terms":{"field":"subtag","size":1000,"all_terms":false},"facet_filter":{"and":[{"term":{"id_group":"1"}}]}}},"filter":{"term":{"id_group":"1"}},"size":20}'

Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed (503 : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[Bvb_RU-XTxmYKE4fX0syXw][prices][4]: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$4@7490df2b]}{[Bvb_RU-XTxmYKE4fX0syXw][prices][3]: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$4@248efb5b]}{[Bvb_RU-XTxmYKE4fX0syXw][prices][2]: EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$2@2718261d]}]","status":503}):
  app/models/price.rb:92:in `search'
  app/controllers/search_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

С чем она может быть связана? В какую сторону копать? Пишите в комментарии, если нужны какие-либо подробности.

---

Сервер elasticsearch работает

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Illusion",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.0.3",
    "build_hash" : "NA",
    "build_timestamp" : "NA",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.6"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

---

Место, в котором происходит ошибка

```
# controller
@prices = Price.includes(:firm, :cost).search(params)

# search.rb
tire.search(load: { include: %w(firm cost) }, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
      query do
        custom_filters_score do
          query do
            # q_converted = params[:q].gsub('.', '').convert_keyboard
            q_converted = params[:q].gsub('.', '').convert_keyboard
            search_query = ["name:'#{q}'"]
            search_query << "name:'#{q_converted}'"           if q != q_converted
            # search_query << "name_first:'#{q.split(' ')[0]}'" if q.split(' ')[0]
            string search_query.join(' '), default_operator: 'OR', analyze_wildcard: true
            # string "name:'#{q}' name:'#{q_converted}'", default_operator: 'OR', analyze_wildcard: true
          end
          if q.split(' ')[0]
            filter do
              filter :term, name_first: q.split(' ')[0]
              boost 5
            end
            filter do
              filter :term, name_second: q.split(' ')[0]
              boost 3
            end
            filter do
              filter :term, name_third: q.split(' ')[0]
              boost 2
            end
            filter do
              filter :term, name_fourth: q.split(' ')[0]
              boost 1.5
            end
          end
          if q.split(' ')[1]
            filter do
              filter :term, name_second: q.split(' ')[1]
              boost 2.0
            end
          end
          if q.split(' ')[2]
            filter do
              filter :term, name_third: q.split(' ')[2]
              boost 1.5
            end
          end
          if q.split(' ')[3]
            filter do
              filter :term, name_fourth: q.split(' ')[3]
              boost 1.2
            end
          end
          score_mode 'total'
        end
      end if params[:q].present?
```

Comment: О-о, я недавно такую же ошибку нашёл на PHPшном (да!) сайте одной крупной торговой сети :) Предполагаю, что связано с тем, что все сервера ElasticSearch лежат.

Comment: @Кнопкатык смотри мой update

Comment: Эм, да, промах, не лежат, просто не смогли (точнее, **не смог**, один же шард) выполнить запрос. Стоит начать с того, что добраться до кода, который этот запрос выполняет.

Comment: @Кнопкатык открою небольшой секрет, сервер какое-то время (25 дней) работал, после чего произошло то, что произошло. Я думаю, это можно (с натяжкой) предполагать, что код валидный.

Comment: Если он со временем перестаёт работать, то чего-то всё-таки не хватает. Начать стоит с запроса, на который в текущем состоянии система отказывается давать ответ.

Comment: @Кнопкатык Любой запрос, в котором присутствует `Price`. А `Price` присутствует в каждом запросе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41154/discussion-between--and-).